# How to get the path of the clicked item in a ListView

Tags: java, android

I am displaying a list of files names in a ListView so i want to get the path of the clicked item

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
//...
}
```

any suggestion?

Comment: How do we know where are you storing your files

Comment: This is where i save my files 
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "folder"

Answer (score 1):

Just get value by position:

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
     String value = (String) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
     //cast it to something else if your object is not String
     //for example
     File file = (File) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
     String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in your code .

```
private List<File> files = new ArrayList<>();
private ListView lv;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            File file = files.get(position);
            String fileName = file.getName();
        }
    });
}
```